# How to show my app in every possible sharing intents and receive them?

Tags: android, sharing, android-sharing

I want my app to be shown in every kind of sharing like plain text, images, videos or any files.
I also want to handle them accordingly. How can I do that? I'm completely new with sharing related stuff and I can't find any proper documentation for it.

Comment: "I can't find any proper documentation for it" -- https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive. "Can I open a BottomSheet(Or something similar) directly without opening the app?" -- what do you mean by "without opening the app"? If you mean "without showing a full-screen activity", have your activity use a dialog them (e.g., `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`), and it will not take up the full screen.

Comment: for the second question. this link may be helpful 
https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-create-a-transparent-activity-in-android

Answer (score 4):

Add this intent filter for receiving all types of sharing intent.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And in your receiving activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    } else {
        Uri fileUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    }
}
```

You will get shared text and file Uri using the above code